# Python Selenium view page source shows JavaScript but inspecting elements shows HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to access links to attachments for a web automation project. The problem is that when I load the web-page via Chrome and inspect element, I can see HTML Code (divs and tables) but when I use the view source option, all I see is JavaScript functions.

Now when I try to access an element via selenium(which has access to source, the JavaScript Code) I can't find any element there. I cannot explicitly find the mention of iFrames, but I think the iFrames that contain this information are being loaded by the JavaScript Code. Is there a way to get access to the underlying HTML to find the elements and get access to the links?

**NOTE :** When I try to view the page source which is a collection of JavaScript functions, there are no links to a frame which can be followed to get the required HTML.

**For context :**

**The inspect element looks like :**

```
<div id="SectionAttachments">
    <table summary="" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td></td>
             <td><img class="attachmentsIcon" src="images/modern_graphite/attachment_url.png" alt="Linked Resource" title="Linked Resource"></td>
             <td class="attachmentTitle">
                <a href="LINK GOES HERE" class="nounderline" title="" target="_blank">Customer View</a>
             </td>
             <td>by</td>
             <td class="attachmentAuthor contact_popover" ivalue="99832"></td>
             <td class="attachmentDate"><span class="dateSpacer">-</span>10/25/2016 04:21:13 AM</td>
             <td width="16">
                <a href="javascript:onAttEdit('IssuePage&amp;Template=atturl&amp;TableId=1003&amp;RecordId=6931123&amp;TableId2=19&amp;Id2=7705574&amp;ProjectId=4581')" class="nounderline" title=""><img align="middle" src="images/modern_graphite/edit.gif" alt="Edit this Attachment" title="Edit this Attachment" border="0"></a>
             </td>
             <td width="16">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                   if(this.eMail)
                   {
                   document.write( "<a href=javascript:eMail('85',99832,document.forms[0].F99832,7705574) style={13}><img src='images/modern_graphite/email.gif' border='0' align='top' alt='Send E-mail' title='Send E-mail'></a>");
                   }
                   else if(parent&&parent.eMail)
                   {
                   document.write( "<a href=javascript:parent.eMail('85',99832,document.forms[0].F99832,7705574) style={13}><img src='images/modern_graphite/email.gif' border='0' valign='bottom' alt='Send E-mail' title='Send E-mail'></a>");
                   }
                </script><a href="javascript:eMail('85',99832,document.forms[0].F99832,7705574)" style="{13}"><img src="images/modern_graphite/email.gif" border="0" align="top" alt="Send E-mail" title="Send E-mail"></a>
             </td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I want to extract the link at "LINK GOES HERE"

**The Page source has no div with ID = "section attachments" or any other elements inside the div. (I searched with corresponding IDs, class names etc, no success)**

**What I have tried :**

- I tried to search the page source from the browser, no results.
- My selenium code tries to search for these elements using XPath, it
  returns no element found.

  XPath expression :

  `driver.get_element_by_xpath("//td[@class = 'attachmentTitle']/a/@href")`
- I have tried putting my script to sleep in case the page isn't fully loaded, no effect.

Is there a way to get these links via selenium? Any help will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT :** 
The problem was resolved by modifying the URL a bit to load a page that renders similarly but has iFrame tags that I can switch to and then find the elements using the same Xpath and get the links.

This page was being loaded after a few redirects from another page. A slight string modification of the URL (using replace in Python) solved the problem. Thanks to all who tried to help.

Comment: Traverse up the DOM and find the `<iframe>` tag and switch to it before trying to locate the elements.

Comment: There is an iFrame tag in the inspect element, but none in the page source. That's the issue. So Selenium can't find the iFrame.

Comment: Update the question with the iframe tag related _HTML_ including the element node incase the element is within the `<iframe>` tag.

Comment: What steps did you take to get the page source?

Comment: Selenium doesn't look at the view source... it looks at the HTML rendered in the browser. That's the equivalent of using the inspect tool in Chrome. Base your locators on that, add a switch into the IFRAME, and make sure you add a wait.

Answer (score 0):

get element by -

```
ele = driver.get_element_by_xpath("//td[@class = 'attachmentTitle']/a")
```

then retrieve element attribute using -

```
 ele.get_attribute('href')
```

Comment: Yeah, I corrected that already, doesn't work. Like I specified, Can't find the element in page source.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are few things that you may be mixing together:

1. When you view the page source in the browser, you're shown the html as it was sent from the server. This html can contain JavaScript that creates elements dynamically, but in the html itself you'd see only the JavaScript code that creates them.
2. The DOM which is what you see when you inspect element, is the current structure of the page. Initially it's pretty much the same as the html, but may include elements that were created or changed dynamically using JavaScript after the page was loaded from the server. This is also what Selenium interacts with.
3. (Not sure if you mentioned it, but for the sake of completeness) driver.page_source returns a string which represents that DOM (current state), but as a valid html format.
4. An html page can contain nested pages using the iframe tag. Each (parent or nested) page had its own html source and its own DOM. In Selenium you have to explicitly switch between them using the driver.switch_to method. Note that on the browser's dev tools though (ie, inspect element), the DOMs of all pages appear combined as one.